# How to Develop our own app which receives the Notification when Near to Beacons.Is there any sample code , if have please suggest me

Tags: ibeacon, beacon, eddystone, android-ibeacon, eddystone-url

How to Develop our own app which receives the Notification when Near to Beacons.Is there any sample code, if have please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

See sample code here:  http://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html

The full reference app will send a notification when a beacon is detected in the background.

https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library-reference

Comment: Is this Code will Work for Virtual Beacons.(Beacon Simulator)

Comment: Yes, you can use the sample app with a software beacon transmitter (iOS or Android.)